# why the added column is not presented?

Tags: python, dataframe

Given that, i have made the `historyMatrix` dataframe as below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    historyMatrix = pd.DataFrame()

    for ind in range(1,10):
        paitent_ID =  np.random.randint(100,500,1)[0]
        year = np.random.randint(2002,2020,1)[0]
        state = np.random.randint(1,5,1)[0]
        historyMatrix.loc[paitent_ID, year] = state

historyMatrix.to_csv("./historyMatrix.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

when i print the `historyMatrix` i have the below result:

```
     2019  2016  2017  2006  2003  2007  2010
371   4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
122   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
106   NaN   NaN   4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
298   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
466   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN
435   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN
497   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN
471   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN
410   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

I tried to build thethe ***paitent_ID***  column using this code:

```
paitent_ID =  np.random.randint(100,500,1)[0]
```

But when i save my dataframe, then paitent_ID colume (which starts by `371` ) does not exist.

How can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `patient_ID` as index, remove `index=False` from your code when you save it to csv, it should look like this:

```
historyMatrix.to_csv("./historyMatrix.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reset index before saving the df

```
historyMatrix.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

then save

```
historyMatrix.to_csv('historymatrix.csv')
```